# How to have a chroot system mount shared with its host?

Tags: bash, mount, chroot, synchronization, busybox

Say I `chroot`ed into `~/myroot` with its `/mnt` being bind-mounted from the host's `/mnt`. Now (from *within* the `chroot` environment) I want to e.g. `mount /dev/something /mnt/something` such that not only the host's `~/myroot/mnt/something` but also *its* `/mnt/something` contains this mount. How can this be achieved?

Unfortunately, the `mount` command of `busybox` doesn't seem to implement `--make-shared` mentioned [here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt?id=HEAD), which should make `mount --make-shared --bind /mnt ~/myroot/mnt` run on the host make this work (untested though!), so how can this be achieved with `busybox`?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you can't do this: you can't mount something to a directory outside the chroot from within the chroot.

Comment: @Gilles Shouldn't a host's `mount --make-shared --bind /mnt ~/myroot/mnt` work like this? Anyway, it is pretty certainly possible, though [my ugly prototype](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/100988/863) is probably not the best solution... **edit** I think I see what you meant, I'll improve my question

Comment: `--make-shared` affects mounts done under another mount. It can allow mounts done in a chroot to leak outside the chroot, but only if the area outside the chroot had first been shared with an area within the chroot.

Comment: @Gilles So that's precisely what I want to achieve. Unfortunately busybox siltently ignores `--make-shared` and `-o shared`

Answer (score 1):

I think the busybox option you need is `-o shared`.

Comment: I'm afraid this has the same effect, namely `mount` silently ignoring this :(

Answer (score 1):

**Prototype!**

A way to do this would be the following script running on the host:

```
#!/bin/bash
# host: bind-mount
PREFIX="~/myroot"
MNT="/mnt"

MNT=${MNT#/}
CMD=$PREFIX/$MNT/.mounts.cmd
OUT=$PREFIX/$MNT/.mounts.out
ERR=$OUT
#ERR=$PREFIX/$MNT/.mounts.err


echo "Using prefix $PREFIX"
if ! [ -d $PREFIX/$MNT ]; then
    mkdir -p $PREFIX/$MNT
    echo "Created $PREFIX/mnt"
fi
for i in $CMD $OUT $ERR; do
    if ! [ -e $i ]; then
        mkfifo $i
        echo "Created $i"
    fi
done

trap "exit 0" SIGINT

while true; do
(   # subshell for better output redirection
    line=$(cat $CMD)
    # FIXME there's a problem if this script doesn't react fast
    # enough such that .mounts.cmd contains more than one line...

    # This is a VERY primitive parser of arguments that will fail
    # in many situations, hence PROTOTYPE
    if [ "$line" == "QUIT" ]; then
        exit 254;
    fi
    isopttype=false
    for para in $line; do
        if $isopttype; then
            switches="$switches$para "
            isopttype=false
        else
            case $para in
                -a)
                    echo "mount -a not supported!" >&2
                    exit 253
                    ;;
                -o|-O|-t)
                    isopttype=true
                    switches="$switches$para "
                    ;;
                -*)
                    switches="$switches$para "
                    ;;
                *)
                    if [ -z "$src" ]; then
                        src=$para
                    elif [ -z "$dest" ]; then
                        dest=$para
                    else
                        echo "Confused by $para after src=$src and dest=$dest" >&2
                        exit 252
                    fi
                    ;;
            esac
        fi
    done

    if [ -z "$src" ] || [ -z "$dest" ]; then
        echo "Please provide both mount source and destination!" >&2
        exit 251
    fi
    mount $PREFIX/${src#/} $dest $switches && mount --bind $dest $PREFIX/${dest#/}
) >>$OUT 2>>$ERR
[[ $? == 254 ]] && exit 0
done

for i in $CMD $OUT $ERR; do
    rm $i
done
```

It listens to a named pipe (`~/myroot/mnt/.mounts.cmd`), which the `chroot`ed `mount` will write to instead of doing an actual mount, and after mounting on the host bind-mount the new mount to the `chroot`-environment.

The `chroot`ed `mount` is replaced by this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# chroot: talk to hosts mount-listener
MNT="/mnt"

CMD=$MNT/.mounts.cmd
OUT=$MNT/.mounts.out
ERR=$OUT
#ERR=$MNT/.mounts.err

echo "$@" > $CMD
cat < $OUT  # TODO output $ERR to stderr
```